# C# Regex capturing parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble capturing parentheses.

I have a big file with data of this form:

```
I.u[12] = {n: "name1",...};
I.u[123] = {n: "name2",...};
I.u[1234] = {n: "name3",...};
```

I want to create a system which helps me get the name (here `name1`, `name2`, `name3`) out of the file if I provide the id (here `12`, `123`, `1234`). I have the following code:

```
    public static string GetItemName(int id)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^I.u\["+id+@"\]\s=\s{n:\s(.+),.+};$");
        Match m= GetMatch(regex,filepath);
        if(m.Success) return m.Groups[0].Value;
        else return "unavailable";
    }

    public static Match GetMatch(Regex regex, string filePath)
    {
        Match res = null;
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                res = regex.Match(line);
                if (res.Success) break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The regex finds the correct line in the file but I really don't know why it doesn't extract the name as I wanted and,

```
if(m.Success) return m.Groups[0].Value;
```

returns me the whole line in the file and not the name... I tried a lot of things, even changing `m.Groups[0]` to `m.Groups[1]` but it didn't work.

I have searched for a moment now without success. Would you have an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: can you explain why "m.Groups[1] ... didn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I can see that you are using a greed quantifier: `.+`. This will match as much as possible. You want a passive modifier, which will only match as much as necessary: `.+?`

Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^I.u\["+id+@"\]\s=\s\{n:\s(?<Name>.+?),.+\};$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Then:

```
if(m.Success) return m.Groups["Name"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this:

```
if(m.Success) return m.Groups[0].Value;
```

Should be:

```
if(m.Success) return m.Groups[1].Value;
```

However, this will return `"name1"` including the quotes. Try and amend your regex pattern to:

```
@"^I.u\["+id+@"\]\s=\s{n:\s""(.+)"",.+};$"
```

which will exclude the quotes from `m.Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are referring to wrong group number..It should be `1` not `0`

Group `0` would always contain the whole match regardless of how many groups you have..

Also the regex should be

```
^I.u\["+id+@"\]\s*=\s*{n:\s*""(.+)"",.+};$
```

Comment: The OP did say that "m.Groups[1] ... didn't work", although s/he failed to explain why.